# Automatically remove tag when message is replied to

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to create/configure a tag that gets automatically removed when a message is replied to? Right now I'm using one of the two options which require additional manual work:

1. Read mail, tag with "To Do", eventually reply, remove the tag manually.
2. Read mail, mark as unread, eventually reply (requires to mark as unread every time I look at the message even though I don't reply yet).

Using option 1. with 'auto-remove tag' would help reduce the manual work.

Comment: Doubt it's of any help since you've probably noticed this and are looking for something more, but... The state of a message should already be automatically indicated by an arrow icon (or lack thereof) to the left of the subject. A message replied to should have a bluish left-pointing arrow icon to the left of its subject, while no icon is shown if it's not been replied to.

Comment: @DavidYockey Indeed however there are many mails I haven't replied to because they don't require a reply at all. I'd like to filter those messages I haven't replied to yet but still want to reply to (hence the "to do" tag). Just filtering for messages without reply will yield many false-positive results. Maybe working with folders would resolve this, or filtering for both, a tag and the without-reply status. I don't know if that's possible though.